# Can I use exec() in Expo?

Tags: javascript, electron, expo

I'm thinking about using Expo to develop an application that works on both desktop and mobile. However, only on the desktop app, I would like to be able to run `child_process.exec()`.

Namely, I would like to run a selenium webdriver using the Expo application.

Is that possible? If so, is it different than using Electron (which I am currently using to develop the desktop app)?

What are the limitations of using Expo for running such child processes?

Will I lose the IPC that Electron provides?